# Can't get ajax request to work in jquery with json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, angularjs

This is for the socket.io chat site called cytu.be. I know the msg code is correct. I guess ajax isn't working here for some reason though. I found this cors-server link from some angularjs code on github thinking it might work. Any possibility of making this link work? (warning: sorry it has explicit pornographic words in it)

```
        if (msg.indexOf('$add ') === 0) {
            term = msg.split('$add ')[1].split(",");
            surl = 'http://cors-server.getup.io/url/api.redtube.com/?data=redtube.Videos.searchVideos&search='+term;
            $.ajax({url: surl,
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    Data = JSON.parse(data.responseText),
                    socket.emit("chatMsg", {
                        msg: Data.videos[0].video.video_id
                    });
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: Did u looked browser console? is there any error like cross origin ?

Comment: thank you for the reply. I've never done browser console before but I'm assuming this is what I'm looking for...Mixed Content: The page at 'https://cytu.be/r/PornLounge' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://cors-server.getup.io/url/api.redtube.com/?data=redtube.Videos.searchVideos&search=something'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.send @ jquery-1.11.0.min.js:3

Comment: I made corrections. my error message now is...Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'videos' of undefined$.ajax.success @ pornlounge.js?dl=0&_=1443473155423:2602oe.Callbacks.c @ jquery-1.11.0.min.js:2oe.Callbacks.d.fireWith @ jquery-1.11.0.min.js:2n @ jquery-1.11.0.min.js:3oe.ajaxTransport.e.send.t @ jquery-1.11.0.min.js:3....for the code....`$.ajax({url: surl,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
      Data = data.responseText;
      socket.emit("chatMsg", {
       msg: Data.videos[0]
      });
        }
    });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are setting `dataType` to be `json`, you do not need to then `JSON.parse()` the response, as jQuery will perform the parsing for you.  In your case, that means you would need to change this line:

```
Data = JSON.parse(data.responseText), // note you also have typo here as this should be semicolon at end of line not a comma
```

to this:

```
Data = data.responseText;
```

It is hard to say if you have any other problems (i.e. CORS-related issues) as you did not post any debugging info in your question. These issues should definitely be fixed though.